# IOS SWIFT 2 - Http Post json array to server

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I want to send data from my iOS app to a PHP sever in JSON format. I am doing this at the backend with the following code:

```
 $json = $_POST['json'];
 $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

 $email         = $data['email'];
 $user_password = $data['password'];
```

I want to send data in a JSON variable such that I can accept the data in 
the JSON variable and then extract the fields one by one.

At the moment, I am doing this in my iOS app with the following Swift code:

```
func login(){
        let email:NSString = txtEmail.text!
        let password:NSString = txtPassword.text!
        let post:NSString = "username=\(email)&password=\(password)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://example.com/test.php")!

        let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData?
        do {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            reponseError = error
            urlData = nil
        }

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                do {
                    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    let success:NSInteger = jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                    NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

I think I have to send a JSON array, but I don't know how can I save the variables in the array and send the JSON array to the PHP server. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you need to implement this from scratch instead of using alamofire + swiftyjson?

Comment: @tskulbru I am new in IOS and I am not familiar with these libraries which you named

Comment: OK, well then I'll highly recommend using them. Makes things easier for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an array of dictionaries:

```
var user_outer_arrary = [[String:Any]]()
var user_inner_array = [String: Any]();
var jsonData : Data? = nil

let user_data :[String:Any]=["email": email,"password": password];

user_outer_arrary.append(user_data);
user_inner_array=["json": user_outer_arrary]
```

Then convert to JSON:

```
do
{
    jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: user_inner_array, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
}
catch
{
}
```